# solaris gcc lib question

Tags: gcc, solaris, sparc

just compiled gcc on solaris 2.10.
My question: what is the difference between the lib/...so and lib/sparcv9/...so files ?

```
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.la
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.a
.../lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6.0.14-gdb.py

.../lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
.../lib/libstdc++.so.6
.../lib/libstdc++.so
.../lib/libstdc++.la
.../lib/libstdc++.a
.../lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14-gdb.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lib/ ones are 32-bit images, the sparcv9/ ones are 64-bit. Try `file *` on each set.